# How to loop in all CheckBoxList then populate them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have 5 Checkboxlist in my aspx file. Is there a way to populate each Checkboxlist using a foreach loop? so that I will not repeating the code to populate each checkboxlist. Below is my code to populate the checkboxlist

```
CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dataTable.dbdata(sqlRawItems, 1);
CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "StudentName";
CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "StudentID";
CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: No, I have a class in which I can pass the sql parameter to get their own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void PopulateIt(CheckBoxList chk,string dataTextField, 
             string dataValueField,sqlRawItems) //I don't really know what sqlRawItems is
{
  chk.DataSource = dataTable.dbdata(sqlRawItems, 1);
  chk.DataTextField = dataTextField;
  chk.DataValueField = dataValueField;
  chk.DataBind();
}
```

Then you can call it wherever you need it.

```
PopulateIt(CheckBoxList1,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);
PopulateIt(CheckBoxList2,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);
PopulateIt(CheckBoxList3,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);
PopulateIt(CheckBoxList4,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);
PopulateIt(CheckBoxList5,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);
```

I'm not sure how `ASP.Net` works, but in winform you could do somthing like this for looping through your controls

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBoxList>())
{  
   //Of cource assuming that all the controls will bind by same data
   PopulateIt(chk ,"StudentName","StudentID",sqlRawItems);        
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your help. It helped me big. hehehe  I just applied array for my checkboxlistS and I used for loop instead. this code doesnt work/recognized this.Controls.OfType<CheckBoxList>() but it gave me an Idea. Again, thanks a lot. I'm a c#/asp.net programmer, just saw your profile you said u've waisted time in c# . why?

Comment: @FrancisSaul Glad I could help. I said it because I saw there's a whole world out there and comparing to the rest of the world I saw, `.Net` is very limited and can be very frustrating (I'm working c# for about ten years or so now). Just look how powerful python, java, javascript and others are..